# Is this possible to download my URLs stored in the Firefox Sync system?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I would like to have a copy of the URLs I have stored on my Firefox Sync Account. Is it possible to have a copy of that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/756111

But you might be able to write something yourself:

http://vanderwijk.info/2011/8/14/accessing-firefox-sync-data-from-python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088817/how-to-access-firefox-sync-bookmarks-without-firefox